# vue / vuetify dynamically modify v-text-field properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I've got a couple fields:

```
<v-row>
    <v-col cols="12" class="d-flex">
        <v-text-field clearable outlined required :rules="rules.codeRules" name="code" v-model="attribute.code" label="Code"></v-text-field>
    </v-col>
</v-row>
<v-row>
    <v-col cols="12" class="d-flex">
        <v-text-field clearable outlined required :rules="rules.nameRules" name="name" v-model="attribute.name" label="Name"></v-text-field>
    </v-col>
</v-row>
```

In Vuetify's documents I see there's a couple properties named `error` which triggers an error state and `error-messages` with messages to be displayed.

When the form's submitted, if there's any errors on any of the fields I want to trigger these properties.

How can I do that? For instance, how can I manually set the field with the name of "code" into an error state by using the `error` property? how can I pass a personalized message to it? Do I need to specifically create a variable in the `data()` object in order to do what I wanna do? because if I have to do it that way it'd mean that I need to create an error and an error-messages properties in the `data` object for each and every field in my form!? or it can do by selecting exactly the field that I want to modify and somehow update its properties directly without the need of any variable from the model?

Thanks

---

**Edit**

Here's what I'm doing:

```
<v-row>
    <v-col cols="12" class="d-flex">
        <v-text-field clearable outlined required :error="formErrors.code.error" :error-message="formErrors.code.errorMessages" :rules="rules.codeRules" name="code" v-model="attribute.code" label="Code"></v-text-field>
    </v-col>
</v-row>
```

My submit method is the following:

```
axios.post(postUrl, this.attribute, { Accept: "application/json" })
    .then(response => {

        if (response.data.success) {
            Event.fire('message', {
                type: 'success',
                message: 'Attribute successfully saved'
            });
            this.$router.push('/attributes/list')
        }
    })
    .catch(errors => {

        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log(errors.response.data)

        const responseErrors = errors.response.data

        if (responseErrors) {
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
            console.log('here modafucka')
            //const self = this
            for (const key of Object.keys(responseErrors)) {
                // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                console.log(responseErrors[key][0])
                this.formErrors[key].error = true;
                this.formErrors[key].errorMessages = responseErrors[key][0];


            }
        }


    })
}
```

By setting `this.formErrors[key].error = true;` I'm able to put the field in an error state, but still the customized error message is not being displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need both `error` and `error-messages` prop. If you just set `error-messages`, the input field will go in error state and the message will be shown

> Do I need to specifically create a variable in the data() object in
>   order to do what I wanna do? because if I have to do it that way it'd
>   mean that I need to create an error and an error-messages properties
>   in the data object for each and every field in my form!

Yes, you'll need to set `error-messages` prop for each and every field. You already have separate variables for `v-model` and `rules`.

Ideally you would be running a for loop to generate the input fields(shown below), but a simple `:error-messages="errorMessages.code"` & `:error-messages="errorMessages.name"` will also work.

```
// Fields array
[
  {
    name: 'code',
    rules: [ // list of rules ],
    value: '' // Some value,
    errorMessages: [] // Could be list or string
  },
  {
    name: 'name',
    rules: [ // list of rules ],
    value: '' // Some value,
    errorMessages: [] // Could be list or string
  }
]
```

```
// Your form template
<v-row v-for="field in fields" :key="field.name">
    <v-col cols="12" class="d-flex">
        <v-text-field 
          clearable 
          outlined 
          required 
          :rules="field.rules" 
          :name="field.name" 
          v-model="field.value" 
          :label="field.name"
          :error-messages="field.errorMessages"
         >
         </v-text-field>
    </v-col>
</v-row>
```

Comment: the error I want to trigger doesn't come from the validation rules but from the server. On error, I tried populating the errorMessages array as you suggested but still the error is not being triggered

Comment: Please share your code in your question, so that the community can take a better look at what you are doing to add error messages?

Comment: The prop name is `error-messages` (plural) and not `error-message`. Can you fix this and try once more.
If that does not work, we'll need to fix how the array is assigned to `this.formErrors[key]`. Nested objects always cause problem with reactivity in VueJS

Comment: Yes, that made the trick. Thanks a lot, I appreciate your help